# When is traffic slow on CrossValidated?

Tags: support, tags, editing, participation

A frequent recommendation (e.g., [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3101/1352) and [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2748/1352)) for retagging or otherwise editing multiple questions is to do it when traffic is slow. Then edit-bumped posts will only push older questions off the first page. However, I have zero intuition of when traffic at CrossValidated is slow, or when it is busy.

When is traffic slow or busy around here?

(I'd assume that this is also relevant for other SE sites and was tempted to ask at [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=when+is+traffic+slow), but I guess answers will differ between sites, and I don't know whether to expect a simple query that one could customize for different sites as an answer to the "general" question.)

Comment: I think that the rate at which you are tagging old questions is fine. I know that does not directly answer your question, but after 10 hours, perhaps nobody knows.

Comment: +1. I'd love to see a plot that shows the average number of new posts (or answers, or edits, or whatever) as a function of GMT hour.

Comment: @amoeba, if you go to `tools` -> `stats` -> `site analytics`, you can see such plots.

Comment: Really, you can just look at the main page. Sometimes, new (answered / modified) questions just keep popping up; other times, it might be 5 or 10 minutes before the list is bumped.

Comment: @gung: [access to site analytics unfortunately only happens at 25,000 rep](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

Comment: @gung and Stephan, oh I was sure that 20k is the maximum rep unlocking all existing privileges (that's partially why I started regularly giving bounties: I thought I don't need any additionally rep anymore). Turns out that it was a false impression and it still makes sense to reach 25k :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on number of posts:

Time of day: Looks like 3:00-7:00 (all times are [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)) is half as busy as 14:00-18:00

day of week: Saturday is the least busy day, followed by Sunday

combined: 6:00-7:00 Saturday is just over 20% as busy as 15:00-16:00 Wednesday

via this query --

http://data.stackexchange.com/stats/query/51030/posts-by-day-of-week-and-hour-of-day

[image: CrossValidated Traffic]

```
foo <- read.table("http://data.stackexchange.com/stats/csv/51030",
  sep=",",header=TRUE)[1:24,1:8]
foo$Hour <- as.numeric(as.character(foo$Hour))
with(foo,plot(Hour,Monday,type="o",pch=19,
  xlab="Hour (UTC)",ylab="",ylim=range(c(0,foo[,-1]))))
for ( ii in 3:8 ) with(foo,lines(Hour,foo[,ii],type="o",pch=19,col=ii-1))
legend("bottomright",lwd=1,pch=19,col=1:7,legend=colnames(foo)[-1])
```

More practically, just avoid the very busiest times (15:00 $\pm$ 3 or 4 hours on weekdays) and if you don't do too many per day (I'd suggest you don't take up more than about a fifth of the front page with bumped posts, for example) you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you! I took the liberty of turning that query into a plot. Will accept unless something unexpectedly better comes along.

Comment: I like how Friday  on this plot starts as a weekday but ends as a weekend.

Comment: @Stephan Thanks for adding the plot