# Why is "kjetil b halvorsen" bumping up old and closed questions?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions, editing

Our active statistican `kjetil b halvorsen` is consistently modifying old questions by adding/removing tags. This [closed](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253853/joint-correlation-in-r) question is an example. The bumped questions is making me harder to navigate the recent problems. Consequently, it's contributing the [widen gap between questions and answers](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5325/we-have-a-very-large-widening-gap-between-questions-and-answers-how-do-we-fix).

May I ask the point of bumping the old and closed question?

Comment: I believe @Kjetil is doing a useful job in principle (most threads that he retags/bumps are not closed), but I agree that in this particular case he got carried away. This question should be deleted, not retagged. I downvoted it now so that it quickly gets automatically deleted (as negatively scored closed Q with no answers).

Comment: Closed questions may potentially reopen; part of the reason questions are closed in the first place is so they can be improved. If a closed question should have a tag, it should have a tag. If that helps it attract an answer (say because it's now seen by someone searching for questions with that tag), then so much the better. However, we should avoid bumping large numbers of old questions in a row when doing so. (There's a meta question on that issue here somewhere that suggests only doing small numbers at one time)

Comment: I want to add warm thanks to @kjetil for his hard work on tags. The side-effects are trivial in my view.

Comment: It's best to bump-edit when traffic is slow. Related discussion: [When is traffic slow on CrossValidated?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3106/1352)

Comment: @StephanKolassa But traffic is high on this site. The post was 2016.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc Well, -6 wouldn't hurt me. However, I still believe excessively bumping up old questions by editing tags shouldn't be encouraged.

Answer (score 14):

kjetil b halvorsen is not bumping up old posts. They are improving questions, which in turn bump the questions because that is how Stack Exchange works. kjetil b halvorsen has edited 3,291 posts whereas you have edited 24 posts so far  on CV, so you may not noticed it.

Stack Exchange users have repeatedly asked on main meta to have an option to edit the question without having it bumped to the front page, but to no avail. Feel free to try your luck there if you agree that this is a missing feature.

Comment: Here is one tangentially relevant request. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29394/it-should-be-possible-to-retag-a-question-without-bumping-it-to-the-front-page